# Genuinely vs sincerely

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What is the difference in meaning between *genuinely* and *sincerely*? For example:

> 1. I genuinely look forward to our meetings
> 2. I sincerely look forward to our meetings

Is there any difference? Are these two words synonyms?

I suspect that these two words are synonyms! I checked this [link](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/genuinely):
and it doesn't show *sincerely* in the list.

Comment: They're as close to identical as a synonym can be, at least in this context. Honestly! Sincerely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, "genuinely" and "sincerely" are synonyms, especially in this context.

"[Genuine](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/genuine)ly" has slightly more emphasis on truth (as opposed to fakeness).

"[Sincerely](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sincerely)" has slightly more emphasis on a person's feelings.

---

Here is a context where this difference in meaning shows up more clearly:

> It's the genuine article.

means "It's the real thing", or "It is exactly what you would expect such a thing to be."  "Sincere" does not fit in this sentence.

Comment: This is a convincing answer and "genuinely" this is what I was looking for! thank you for your contribution on this! Sincerely!